# QGIS atlas: make only current polygon visible

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer

I have a layer with lots of polygons and want an atlas that goes through each polygon. However, the atlas page should only show the current polygon and not its neighbors. In the following image only the rectangle with the red lines in it should be visible and the others should be invisible.

[image: only the rectangle with the red lines in it]

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Once you create an atlas there should be additional variables available in the function editor. Use those variables to set up data-dependent visibility for the symbology of that layer. Have a look at other questions tagged with `atlas` and `qgis` - I'm sure this has been answered before. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis+atlas

Answer (score 4):

This is controlled by rule styles in the atlas layer Symbology property:

1. Set the layer property>Symbology to Rule-based
2. Create one style for active atlas feature symbol and another blank/empty style for non atlas features
3. For each rule/style set the filter expression as (ogc_fid is the feature id field):

   "ogc_fid"  =  @atlas_featureid (for atlas feature rule)

   "ogc_fid"  <>  @atlas_featureid (for non atlas feature rule)

This should only show the active atlas feature when the atlas is enabled.